# SlidingUpPanel: Cannot Assign Listeners to UI Elements

Tags: android, android-sliding

How can I implement listeners to GUI elements in second layout in SlideUpPanel view. In the demo example I can't assign my own listeners to elements that are contained in a panel. After I press on the panel layout, the panel is collapsed. How did other people get the panel to contain a ScrollView like in the Umano App?